# jQuery UI Sortable - saving order when button clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, serialization

I have a list with items that should be sorted by the user with jQuery UI Sortable. After the user has chosen his final order of the list he has to click a button "Ready". After the button is clicked, the order should be sent to saveoder.php using serialize and Ajax.

I tried to surround the ajax call with a click event but then there will be a couple of POST-requests done depending on the count of sortable actions of the user. I need only one ajax post request.

```js
$(function() { 
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {  
   var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
   
   $(document).on("click", "button" , function() { //that doesn't work
    $.ajax({
     data: order,
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'saverank.php'
    });
   });
  }
 }).disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="id_1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="id_2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="id_3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
<button>Ready</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a builtin method for doing this. Refer [serialize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) or [toArray](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/539/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            $(document).on("click", "button", function () { //that doesn't work
                $.ajax({
                    data: order,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'saverank.php'
                });
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var r = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        var a = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {
            attribute: "id"
        });
        console.log(r, a);
    });
});
```

Comment: for me this code does not send only one ajax call, instead it sends number of ajax calls based on the count of sortable actions on single click

Comment: @Rsganesh Check if you are binding the events multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
For single ajax call. Modified from accepted answer

$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        }
    }).disableSelection();
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var a = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {
            attribute: "id"
        });
        console.log(a);
        $.ajax({
            data: a,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'saverank.php'
        });
    });
});
```